# XMLHTTPResquest.setRequestHeader() is not adding custom page headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, soap, xmlhttprequest

I'm attempting to use AJAX to call make a SOAP call (not cross-site, so it shouldn't run into difficulties with proxies, etc.)
However, this requires two custom headers in the XHR, SOAPTarget and SOAPAction. Currently, I'm using jQuery to make the ajax call like so:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: this.location,
        type: 'POST',
        data: sm,
        dataType: "xml",            
        contentType: "text/xml",
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader(
                "SOAPTarget",
                this.location
            );
            xhr.setRequestHeader(
                "SOAPAction",
                this.urn
            );
        },      
        success: jQuery.jSOAPClient.success,
        error: jQuery.jSOAPClient.error
    });
```

The code all executes as expected, however when I view the headers in Firebug, there's no change to them.

Comment: Ran a test and it worked for me on Safari and FF. Make sure you check the "request headers". After that, check on the server side just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! It's interesting that that worked for you. The answer in the end turned out to be a scoping issue. I don't suppose you have a copy of the test you ran?

Comment: As a side note, I've been using the "header:" tag in place of "beforeSend".  `headers: {SOAPAction: requestList[reqItem].SOAPAction, SOAPTarget: requestList[reqItem].SOAPTarget}`  It avoids the overhead of the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XHR will not accept a request header with a null value and, as it turns out, the `this` in this block refers to the Ajax call rather than the object that the ajax call is part of.

This question should probably be renamed "noob mistakes happen".

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem. Instead of using 'beforeSend' try using [ajaxSend](http://jsfiddle.net/Gq3wH/).

Comment: Whilst this didn't work, it helped me step through the code to just the right place. Turns out the XHR wont set a new header with a blank value, and the variables I was calling were in the wrong scope. Thanks!